# slideToggle on multiple divs that aren't near the clickable element

Tags: jquery

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xhuLZ/

The next step, which I'm unsure how to get to, is to have it so that when a div is open and another element that has a separate div is clicked, opens and closes the already opened div. (It's late, so I hope that makes sense!)

I've seen plenty of examples that are **close** to what I'm trying to achieve, but with the hidden div right next to the element that is to be clicked (to show/hide) and that doesn't affect already open divs.

Comment: do you mean to remove opened div when another link is clicked ?

Comment: Whoa, I'm way late to my own party... Anyway, yes, Eric, that's what I meant. I played around with it some more and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/tUQKG/  It's 99% there. All that's left is getting the link that has an open div to close completely when it's clicked on a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/xhuLZ/1/

It's pretty easy actually, you just have to slideUp() all the visible subnav-panel:

```
$('.subnav-panel:visible').slideUp();
```